# Is there any way to run command line from iOS on MacOS

Tags: macos, ios, terminal

So what I’m curious about is that if it is possible to run the command line on iPhone so that it will run on Mac.

For example:

Say, that there is a GitHub project on Mac and I forgot to commit. And is this possible to run command (using Shortcuts or smth else) from iPhone, so that the project on Mac will be committed

Comment: ssh questions: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69163/which-options-exist-for-ssh-tunneling-clients-on-ios https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/348009/connecting-from-ios-to-macos-using-ssh

Comment: Along with SSH you can install one of the many remote access applications for the iPhone/iPad/Mac. I've always been wary of opening up outside ports, so I tend to prefer remote access apps like Logmein/TeamViewer/Splashtop that are a bit safer. Bonus is you can do anything you want on your computer from your phone - not just this specific task.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any SSH app on iOS to access the command line on a Mac.

On the Mac you want to open **System Preferences** => **Sharing** and enable **Remote Login**.

On the iOS device you want to install an SSH app, such as for example [Terminus](https://termius.com) from the App Store.

You can then use Terminus to connect to the Mac using its IP address and your user name and password.